# Connect PS Vita to Ubuntu?

Tags: games, sony

I have recently purchased a PS (Playstation) Vita. I want to add music and videos to the device, but I can not seem to get it to connect to Ubuntu. Apparently, you need a content manager available only to Mac and Windows.

Does anyone know how to connect a Vita to Ubuntu for file transfers?

Comment: I've been trying to do this with a virtual machine...and failing:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/377748/connect-ps-vita-to-virtual-machine-on-13-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it (yet!), but apparently there's an Open Source version of "Content Manager" that has been developed for connectivity with the PlayStation Vita:
[QCMA](http://wololo.net/talk/viewtopic.php?t=34677)

Most of the users at that link claim it works for them, so I'm gonna test it out as soon as my PlayStation Vita is charged...

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to transfer content to a vita from linux systems.
You need to use content manager assistant for windows or mac OS.
You can also use a ps3 to transfer content.

Answer (score 0):

Content manager requires Windows Media Player if you download the Windows version of the Content Manager Assistant. You cannot use Windows Media Player on Ubuntu as far as I can see. I haven't been able to use it through Wine. Validation even on older versions of the WMP won't install.

Comment: Windows Media Player 10 for Ubuntu has a Gold rating on the WineHQ Application Database, so it appears from your answer that the problem is that **validation** won't install. Does this mean that validation is somehow separate from the Windows Media Installation or are you referring to a feature of Windows Media Player that cannot be enabled if you have installed WMP using Wine?

Answer (score 0):

I use Lubuntu on my pc, I transfer music and videos onto my Samsung galaxy S4 then use the S4 as a server to transfer data to my PS Vita.

1. First download and install network media player from apps section in PSN
2. On the S4 go to settings/connections and turn on nearby devices
3. On the vita open network media player
4. Click add or remove servers and your S4 should show up.
5. Click back an your connected and can view all media content from s4 on the ps vita.
6. To copy media to the vita system click the settings tab (bottom right hand corner vita screen)
7. Click copy to memory card, check box next to content you want to copy wait for content to transfer

thats it! you can now view your content on the vita

Answer (score -1):

Try using this `exe` in Wine:

http://cma.dl.playstation.net/cma/win/en/index.html

I hope it works.

Comment: just sasys that i need to install windows media player